# Is it possible to execute AWS CLI commands on an EC2 instance without placing AWS credentials on the EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I have an API server running on a docker container, and the docker container runs on an [AWS ec2 instance](https://aws.amazon.com/tw/ec2/).

Is it possible to make the server execute [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) commands without putting my aws credentials on the docker container?

Because I think the aws credentials should only be placed on my local machine.

I don't think it is safe to place it on a remote machine which can be accessed by other people.

Comment: Not sure about AWS, but Google Cloud has this feature.

Comment: Also, most clouds have an IAM infrastructure that allows you to create more ids/keys that have more limited, fine grained permissions.  Have you tried that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. Attach IAM role to your EC2 instance. No need to place the AWS credentials in the EC2 instance. Your application/CLI will get the credentials automatically.

[IAM Roles for Amazon EC2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html)

- Create an IAM role with necessary privileges.
- Specify the role when you launch your instance, or attach the role to a running or stopped instance.